# Как отменить действие команды и вернуть всё так, как было

Tags: linux, консоль, macos, ssh, config

Я поменял несколько вещей в sshd_config файле (на локальной машине) и захотел вернуть всё назад. Последовав [совету](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393534/how-to-reset-the-sshd-config-file-to-its-default-settings) я ввёл команду `sudo cp /private/etc/ssh/sshd_config ~/.ssh/config` в терминале. Но сама проблема в том, что после выполнения этой команды я теперь не могу подключиться к VPS по ssh и выводит следующего рода ошибку

```
iMac-a:~ derek$ ssh root@1.2.3.4
/Users/derek/.ssh/config: line 41: Bad configuration option: authorizedkeysfile
/Users/derek/.ssh/config: line 82: Bad configuration option: usepam
/Users/derek/.ssh/config: line 106: Bad configuration option: acceptenv
/Users/derek/.ssh/config: line 112: Bad configuration option: subsystem
/Users/derek/.ssh/config: terminating, 4 bad configuration options
```

Как вернуть всё назад, может, есть какой-нибудь способ или может есть возможность разобраться с уже существующими ошибками? Спасибо

Comment: @Andrey исходя из команды, у меня файл `/private/etc/ssh/sshd_config` переместился в `~/.ssh/config`, если это так, то я не могу найти его. Мало того, я не заметил, как проводил такие изменения на локальном компьютере, а не на VPS

Comment: @Andrey я вводил эту команду у себя на домашнем компьютере, то есть в этот момент я **не был** подключен к VPS

Comment: Тогда удалите на локальном компе `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: При удалении выводит `override rw-r--r--  root/staff for /Users/derek/.ssh/config?` следует ввести `y`/`yes`?

Comment: Вы его от root туда скопировали, просто удалите так-же от root через sudo

Comment: Перепишите свой [комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1050136/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%91-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%be?noredirect=1#comment1794040_1050136) в виде ответа, я помечу его решением, спасибо

Comment: На будущее `sudo cp /private/etc/ssh/sshd_config{,_orig}` сохраняете резервную копию ДО ВНЕСЕНИЯ ИЗМЕНЕНИЙ и `sudo cp -f /private/etc/ssh/sshd_config{_orig,}` восстанавливаете из копии

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Удалите от пользователя root файл `~/.ssh/config`
`sudo rm ~/.ssh/config`

Система Вам четко пишет `/Users/derek/.ssh/config: line 41: Bad configuration option: authorizedkeysfile` Она пытается прочитать файл конфигурации подключения, а находит файл конфигурации сервера. Удивляется найдя там директивы которых там быть не должно, о чем Вам и рассказывает.